# What is the difference between "<<<SQL SQL;" and using quotes for a statement

Tags: php, syntax, heredoc

Could anyone provide some sort of documentation on the differences and or benefits of using

```
$sql = <<<SQL
      SELECT COUNT(ParentGUID) 
      FROM siteobjects  
SQL;
```

Instead of using just using.

```
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(ParentGUID) 
      FROM siteobjects";
```

Struggling to find any information on this due to searching for "<<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one uses [`HEREDOC`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax. It's useful when you're working with multi-line strings and to avoid quoting problems. To solve the search issue, you can use a programming search engine that doesn't ignore special characters (like [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3C%3C%3C%20php)).

Comment: Thanks for the search tool and answer!

Comment: @user2661326: Glad to have been of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference except for the fact that the [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) would have white spaces in the start (because of tabulation).

Answer (score 0):

That's PHP Heredocs syntax (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). I prefer heredocs over simple strings because almost any IDE recognize the syntax, and it's more readable, but both options are possible.